# Stop windowing during streaming in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

If it's possible, how can i stop windowing while streaming is running. ? I know that i can change TimeWindow dynamically according to incoming event by using custom WindowAssigner but i don't know how to stop windowing according to incoming event. Otherwise would it be a correct way to do windowing by using ProcessFunction and state holders with timestamp in order to be flexible on starting and stoping windowing ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stop windowing"? Would you like to simply forward every record as if there was no window operator or process each record as if it was in a window with a single record (i.e. itself)?

Comment: @FabianHueske in a specific interval an event stream (keyed) could be windowed, that means all events in a specific window will be processed together. I want it to continue just like there is no window operator and process for each record whenever a specific control event changes window behaviour. Thanks